# Consume Rest resource which download file

Tags: java, rest, rest-client

I am writing Rest client , I am trying to consume rest resource which is mainly for download file with specific name , and file may different format.
   I am able to retrieve data but it is in chunked format so data is not properly render in file (it is in encoded format), 
   And how can I get name of downloaded file from rest client which is consumed by rest resource.

```
@GET
@Path("/download/pdf")
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response downloadPdfFile() {

    // set file (and path) to be download
    File file = new File("D:/Demo/download/Sample.pdf");

    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok((Object) file);
    responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"MyJerseyFile.pdf\"");
    return responseBuilder.build();
}
```

I have this rest resource which I want to consume through rest client and through consume response I should get filename as well e.g. "Sample.pdf".

I am getting correct response when I am consuming this URL from browser or SOAP UI now I want to write rest client in another rest resource so basically I am calling rest service from another rest resource using rest client.

I have written Java client, I am getting byte[] but when I am trying to render this bytes in my file I am getting encoded format data in file and in SOAP UI it is saying , 
Transfer-encoding:chunked

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
    builder.setScheme("http").setHost("localhost:8080")
            .setPath("/download/pdf");
    URI uri = builder.build();
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);     
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);        

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer resultTest = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        resultTest.append(line);
    }
    byte[] byteArr=String.valueOf(resultTest).getBytes();
```

I am using above code as rest client

Comment: Please share you code.

Comment: Why don't you try this "MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE" instead of ""application/pdf""